# Using one method for button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a website which I am currently working on. There are several pages which will included `GridView` where users will be able to download files. Currently I am writing the download method for on each page. Is there a better way to achieve this? i.e. call this method on each click event

I am using the below code

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Write a class, and have each page use the class containing the method. User control. Write a generic handler (ASHX) to do the download response. Many ways.

Comment: @JasonW Can you provide an example please

Comment: I just posted an answer showing a basic generic handler (ASHX) and a static extension method as a second example in case you just are looking to shorten code.

Comment: Just make a static helper class somewhere in your core layer, remember the DRY principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use a generic handler. If it was a small project that I just wanted to shorten code on, you might consider a simple extension method.

**Method 1: Generic Handler**

Write the download into a generic handler. The code below could be "DownloadPdf.ashx" in your website.

```
public class DownloadPdf : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.QueryString["file"]);
        string contentType = Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.QueryString["type"]);
        context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your event handler:

```
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        string url = string.Format("~/DownloadPdf.ashx?contentType={0}&file={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(ContentType), Uri.EscapeDataString(filePath));
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
```

**Method 2: Extensions**

If you're just looking to shorten your code on a simple project, you could write an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void WritePdfDownload(this HttpResponse response, string filePath, string contentType)
    {
        response.ContentType = contentType;
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.WriteFile(filePath);
        response.End();
    }
}
```

Then, your event handlers are very simple:

```
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.WritePdfDownload(filePath, ContentType);
    }
```

Comment: I like your extension idea.

Comment: Thanks for this, The project is fairly small so ill stick with the extension idea.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which you can access from all pages that should be able to Download Files, then in the "onclick()" simply invoke that class.

Answer (score 0):

Write a DownloadFile method in a Static Download class

Replace the "object Response" in the method signature with the type of your Response object.

```
namespace DownloadMethods
{
    internal static class Downloads
    {
        public static void DownloadFile(object sender, object Response)
        {
             string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
             Response.ContentType = ContentType;
             Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
             Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
             Response.WriteFile(filePath);
             Response.End();
         }
    }
}
```

The you can just call this:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DownloadMethods.Downloads.DownloadFile(sender, Response);
}
```

Comment: If he extracts the method like so to helper class, how we will get access to `Response` object from the method?

Comment: I tried something similar but I get errors `Response` and `ContentType` do not exist in the current context

Comment: @Code Ive updated the answer. Pass the Response object to the method too.

Comment: @Code Did you change "object Response" in the method signature to be the type of your response object? Like HttpResponse Response or whatever it is.

Comment: @jjczopek - `Response = HttpContext.Current.Response` will get response. In helper class, you'd have to make sure all right namespaces are imported.

Comment: This method works only for `LinkButton`. Not a good idea to pass `sender` into the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having common logic on the pages, maybe you should consider creating base class with download method, and then just inherit this base class for additional pages.

You would have one implementation of the download method, which would make it easier to maintain.

You could also extract the method that downloads the file into separate class and call if from your pages, however as it looks now, you would need to figure out how to pass other dependencies there, like `Response` object.